# c# tabcontrols can't add panel in another tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have some problem about window form in VS C# . I make a tabcontrol. it 's compound with tabpage1, tabpage2
. All tabpage will add same panel. when I click for switch tab it should show the panel. but It's not work. It' will show first tabpage but it's not show in other tabpage when i switched tab.

```
       public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
           public Form2(.....){
               ..........
              InitializeComponent();
                 ...........
               panelButton.Controls.Add(btnArr1[i]);
               tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panelButton); //It's work
               tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(panelButton); //it's not show panel

               }

           }
```

In another way I try to make event when i click another tabpage. Like this code.

```
      private void tabPage1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
             tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panelButton); //It 's work
        }
```

and

```
        private void tabPage2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(panelButton); //It is not show panel.
        }
```

What Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add the single object (panelButton) in the different tabs. You should create two panelButtons for each tab, or you should to remove panelButton from the current tab, before adding it in the selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add controls with same referece to two different tabPages
the solution is to make a new  instance of panelButton and add it to second tab,
Do Not forget that all contorls inside your panelButton must be init too